# Fast image thinning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I want to implement a fast algorithm for thinning of a binary image. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinning_(morphology))

I know about the Zhang-Suen and Guo-Hall algorithms, but these are very slow as they perform multiple passes over the whole image.

I have found this site (https://sites.google.com/site/rameyarnaud/research/c/voronoi) which announces faster implementations based on the idea of evolving the outline pixels only. Presumably, this approach leads to a linear (wrt the number of pixels)) or slightly superlinear processing time (assuming that every pass takes time proportional to the length of the current outlines, in the end equal to the skeleton size).

On another hand, I know that the skeleton corresponds to ridges in the distance map, and the (morphological) distance map can be computed in linear time. SO I suspect that by local processing of the distance map, the skeleton can be detected, but I don't know exactly how.

So my questions:

- do you know how to detect the skeleton pixels from the distance map, or
- do you know of a published algorithm to perform the thinning in linear time ?

Comment: Do you need a rather smooth skeleton or the actual medial axis? The latter is quite sensitive to noise on the boundary.

Comment: Possibly useful for your first question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection

Comment: It sounds like he makes one pass over all the pixels to capture a table of coordinates of body pixels touching non-body ones. Now he can traverse the table to apply the thinning rules only to body pixels that might be removed. When he removes one, it's relatively easy to update the table if it's stored the right way, e.g. with Morton keys (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I have been using "Efficient Binary Image Thinning using Neighborhood Maps by Joseph M. Cychosz, Graphics Gems IV", itself based on an algorithm by Rosenfeld, which has an acceptable behavior. I guess that it is of the MAT type. Can you confirm ?

Comment: @samgak: maybe but I guess that there should-be an ad-hoc way to find the ridges in those distance maps.

Comment: @gene: I think so too. That should be what they call the "peeling" method in Wikiedia. I am wondering about the time complexity.